# Dynamic Help Input Fields with Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I would like to happen is that when a user clicks on an input feild, they get a help text that will appear on top of the for to tell them what to fill in. At the moment It gets stuck on one message.

#### My HTML

```
<p id="help">Helpful notes will appear here</p>

<p>E-mail:  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />   </p>
<p>Name:    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />     </p>
<p>Age:     <input type="text" id="age" name="age" />       </p>
```

#### My Js

```
function showHelp(help) {
    document.getElementById('help').innerHTML = help;
}

function setupHelp() {
var helpText = [
{'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
{'id': 'name',  'help': 'Your full name'},
{'id': 'age',   'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16 to play game)'}
];

for (var i = 0;  i < helpText.length;  i++ ) {
var item = helpText[i];
document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
    return showHelp(item.help);
  };
}
}
setupHelp();
```

I would greatly appretiate the Help.

#### Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5m5b/) to help you see the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been bitten by the closure bug!

Do this instead:

```
for (var i = 0;  i < helpText.length;  i++ ) {
    var item = helpText[i];

    (function(item) {
        document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
            return showHelp(item.help);
        };
    })(item);
}
```

The problem is that `item` in the `onfocus` handler points to `item` as is defined inside the `for` loop. During every iteration of the `for` loop, the memory location of `item` is updated to the new value and so at the end, each `onfocus` handler is pointing to the same `item`. You have to force a new scope and you can do that by using an immediately-invoked function expression. This effectively defines a new function and calls it immediately thereby creating a new scope. Hence you have a new `item` inside the function for each iteration of the `for` loop and this should make your `onfocus` handler behave as you would expect.

Check out the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/92gPa/).

As [numbers1311407](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178150/numbers1311407) mentioned in the comments, you can also use `forEach` instead of the `for` loop:

```
helpText.forEach(function (item) {
    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
       return showHelp(item.help);
       //showHelp(item.help);
   };        
});
```

This behaves the same way but looks less awkward than using the IIFE. `forEach` is supported in all browsers, but IE 8 and below do not support it.

Comment: @numbers1311407 I like `forEach`; much cleaner!

Comment: `forEach` polyfill can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ;-)

Comment: @numbers1311407 Thanks :) I forgot that there are shims and polyfills you can use now.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath I'm sorry I know that this is an old thread but I still don't understand it, and I have 2 questions. 1. Why would the age display, wouldn't it be email? The first iteration of the loop, item.help is the e-mail address. Why would it refer to the last iteration, I don't get that. My second question is the original OP's question. And wouldn't the return statement; return showHelp(item.help) return 'Your e-mail address' for the first iteration? Thanks.